# How to integrate own php package GitHub project with composer to use as well as develop it simultaneously

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php

I want to develope laravel package
I have created sample project on github with a class.
I use the package name from my github php package `composer.json` in my project `composer.json` in `require{}` array.

When I do `composer update` I get error.
I need illustrative steps to develope and integrate PHP/Laravel package from using Github and composer.

Composer.json for project i am adding my package to, is :

```
    {
       "name": "laravel/laravel",
       "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
       "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
       "license": "MIT",
       "type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "jeroen-g/laravel-packager": "^1.3",
    "igaster/laravel-theme": "^1.1",
    "laura/cms": "*.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/harish-php/lauracms"
}]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Added some more explanation on how to create the custom package

Custom package composer.json

```
{   
    "name": “packageName”,   
    "autoload": {     
        "psr-4": {       
                “MySourcesNamespace\\”: "srcDir”     
        }   
    }
 }
```

Composer.son of application

```
"require": {    
    "packageName": "1.0.*" 
},
"repositories": [   {       
    "type": "vcs",      
    "url":  "https://github.com/…"  
} ]
```

The version here should be tagged. If you do not have a Tag you can depend on the master branch:

```
"require": {    
    "MySourcesNamespace\\": "dev-master" 
},
```

When doing composer update your classes should be inside the vendor directory.

Comment: I did that..i am getting error about minimum stability..Will post detailed error message.

Comment: @harish Ok post the error message and the directory structure of your package

Comment: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laura/cms could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Comment: Ok a familiar error :). Can you post the composer.json where you are including the package?

Comment: Cool .. :) I have dit question.. Waiting for your comments Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I gues to problem is here: "laura/cms": "\*.\*"
Try changing it to "laura/cms": "dev-master"
I saw on your github project you do not have any tags. So composer can't know what version to retrieve. Using dev-master tells composer to use the master branch. I have also edited my answer to include to necessary steps